# how to animate the circle image using CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, quartz-core

I'm new in ios development. 
I'm implementing an `Animation` project and I have a `circle.png` image.

How can I rotate the image using `CAKeyFrameAnimation` on that image?

Answer (score 0):

Code:-

```
-(void)spinAnimation
{

    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    rotation.duration = 1.1; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    [yourimageview.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are using CABasicAnimation.I want CAKeyFrameAnimation

Comment: Any specific reason you needing CAKeyFrameAnimation.

Comment: Yes. How to use the CAKeyFrameAnimation